# "Cannot access org.json.JSONStringer.Scope" on Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Sorry for this probably dumb question, i'm new to Java, Android Studio and everything related.
I'm trying to implement a simple weather forecast app for android on Android Studio 3.2.1 using the [DarkSkyApi](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#forecast-request).
I managed to get the Data from DarkSky's server with HttpsURLConnection, StringBuilder
and BufferedReader. However, when i try to create a new JSONObject(.toString()), it just returns null. Further investigation led me to .toString()->JSONObject.java->JSONStringer, where Android Studio "Cannot access org.json.JSONStringer.Scope", what seems to be causing the failure of .toString().
I did add the JSON-Library, apart from the JSONStringer everything JSON-related looks like it would work. Imports do look fine to me aswell.
This is the malfunctioning code:

```
public class JSONStringer {

/** The output data, containing at most one top-level array or object. */
final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

/**
 * Lexical scoping elements within this stringer, necessary to insert the
 * appropriate separator characters (ie. commas and colons) and to detect
 * nesting errors.
 */
```

enum Scope {

```
    /**
     * An array with no elements requires no separators or newlines before
     * it is closed.
     */
    EMPTY_ARRAY,

    /**
     * A array with at least one value requires a comma and newline before
     * the next element.
     */
    NONEMPTY_ARRAY,

    /**
     * An object with no keys or values requires no separators or newlines
     * before it is closed.
     */
    EMPTY_OBJECT,

    /**
     * An object whose most recent element is a key. The next element must
     * be a value.
     */
    DANGLING_KEY,

    /**
     * An object with at least one name/value pair requires a comma and
     * newline before the next element.
     */
    NONEMPTY_OBJECT,

    /**
     * A special bracketless array needed by JSONStringer.join() and
     * JSONObject.quote() only. Not used for JSON encoding.
     */
    NULL,
}
```

Since i havn't changed anything in the JSONStringer.java i suspect the error maybe refers to a missing dependency or import or something, but i can't figure it out.

And this is where i get the Null-Object

```
if (responceCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTION:::" + connection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            Log.i(TAG, "url:::");
            StringBuilder arg = new StringBuilder(1024);
            String tmp="1";
            while(tmp !=null) {
                tmp = reader.readLine();
                arg.append(tmp).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            Log.i(TAG, "Data: " + arg.toString());


            return new JSONObject(arg.toString());
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
```

Log.i(TAG, "Data: " + arg.toString()); works fine and logs the data-string like it should.
Do you need something else to figure this out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I worked around the JSON lib by manualy extracting the data with String.split()
Not perfect but i got what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JsonObject output = Json.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("data", arg.toString())
     .build();

return output;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When i try your code in Android-Studio, i get "cannot resolve symbol 'Json'". Do i need to add something in dependencies or imports?

These are my current Imports:

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: Well, that wasn't Android specific, so it might be no the best option. Make sure you have a valid JSON-encoded string inside arg.toString()  when you do it your way. Refer to this documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Comment: arg.toString() gets me this:
{"latitude":37.8267,"longitude":-122.4233,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","currently":{"time":1542818024,"summary":"Heavy Rain","icon":"rain","nearestStormDistance":0,"precipIntensity":0.3379,"precipIntensityError":0.0694,"precipProbability":1,"precipType":"rain","temperature":58.83,"apparentTemperature":58.83,"dewPoint":52.72,"humidity":0.8,"pressure":1015.36,"windSpeed":7.26,"windGust":17.67,"windBearing":149,"cloudCover":

...and so on. Looks alright to me? 
Do you have any idea why i can't compile the JSONStringer.java? Why can't it access the enum Scope?

Comment: Do you have org.json.JSONObject imported?

Comment: yes, i do! Do i need to set any specific dependencis or repositorys? I don't really understand what either of them is for.

Comment: build.gradle file is usually the place where you set your dependencies. But it should yell at you if you import something unknown.

Comment: okay thank you anyway. I'll try something else then JSON lib, maybe parse the data-string manualy